# Use Linq to detect circular dependency, string property

Tags: c#, linq

Imagine an object like this

```
public class ContentType
{
    public string Alias { get; set;}
    public string ParentAlias { get; set;}
}
```

And a flat collection of these objects

```
List<ContentType> contentTypes...;
```

How can I use a linq chained syntax query to determine if there is a circular reference in the collection.

```
//Example
ContentType #50
Alias: Truck
ParentAlias: Vehicle

ContentType #90
Alias: Vehicle
ParentAlias: Truck
```

That would be a circular dependency which would break the code that creates the content types (it would get stuck in an infinite loop walking the parent hierarchies..)

So before I process the parent/child content types I would like to first detect if there is a circular dependency in the collection and halt the operation if one is detected.

Comment: Does this has to be LINQ?

Comment: Furthermore why are you using a `string` instead of `ContentType`? This looks like a *design problem*.

Comment: @CommuSoft That's pretty far from the crux of this problem.  Writing a method that computes the `ContentType` object representing the parent when given the `string` is something you can write in just two lines of code.  I also wouldn't call it a *design problem*, as there are plenty of valid reasons for having it that way, it's just one of the smaller puzzle pieces that needs to be solved in the process of solving the larger problem.

Comment: The ContentType is a poco representing deserialized Json.  The content type will be synced against a content management system called Umbraco that stores the object in the database like that.  In order to JSON deserialize into child content type objects I would need to define the json for the child content type which would result in a LOT of duplicated Json data.   The ParentAlias is the key that they reference each other off of and was the simplest way to define the child relation in json.

Sure I could build custom derserializers... but no need imo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So we'll start with two helper methods.  First we'll want a method that yields all of the ancestors for an item, when given that item and a delegate that gets the parent of an item:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Ancestors<T>(T item, Func<T, T> parentSelector)
{
    while (item != null)
    {
        item = parentSelector(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

We'll also write a method to determine if a sequence repeats by storing all of the previously yielded items and seeing if each new item is in that set:

```
public static bool Repeats<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    var set = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in sequence)
        if (!set.Add(item))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

From here we can determine if any sequence contains cycles by computing the ancestors of each item and determining if any of those collections repeat:

```
public static bool ContainsCycles<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    Func<T, T> parentSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    return sequence.Any(item => Ancestors(item, parentSelector).Repeats(comparer));
}
```

All that's left is to write a method that computes the parent of each item, since that's not an operation your class already supports, which can be done by just creating a lookup from the alias to the item and then using it:

```
IEnumerable<ContentType> types = CreateContentTypes();
var lookup = types.ToDictionary(type => type.Alias);
bool anyCycles = ContainsCycles(types, type => lookup[type.ParentAlias]);
```

---

As far as performance, and possible improvements, if you're dealing with particularly large trees/subtrees, you could cache the results of the intermediate calculations.  For example, if we have a node A, and a parent B, and a grandparent C, which is a root, then when doing a calculation to determine if A is in a cycle we also need to determine if B is in a cycle.  If we already determined if B was in a cycle earlier, and cached it, we could skip that step.  if we didn't, then we could cache it when doing the cycle calculator for A, and then we won't need to do it again when checking B later.

This does complicate the code a fair bit, so if you don't have a particularly large/deep graph, you may choose not to bother caching these intermediate results and just choose to re-calculate them for each item:

```
public static bool IsInCycle<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    HashSet<T> itemsNotInASequence,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    var set = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        if (itemsNotInASequence.Contains(item))
            return false;
        else if (!set.Add(item))
            return true;
    }
    itemsNotInASequence.UnionWith(set);
    return false;
}

public static bool ContainsCycles<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence,
    Func<T, T> parentSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    var itemsNotInASequence = new HashSet<T>(comparer);
    return sequence.All(item => Ancestors(item, parentSelector)
        .IsInCycle(itemsNotInASequence));
}
```